# Why is this nginx proxy_pass not working?

Tags: nginx

I have two Node.js applications: one running on port `8080` and the other on port `4040`.

Nginx is correctly sending requests from `http://localhost/` to `http://localhost:8080` and the homepage loads fine.

But if I `POST` to `http://localhost/services/processor/api/format` it is not working. I get an error saying cannot POST to `/services/processor/api/format`. I expect it to send the `POST` request to `http://localhost:4040/api/format`.

If I `POST` something directly to `http://localhost:4040/api/format` then it works fine.

I don't understand where the problem lies.

**nginx.conf:**

```
   #user  nobody;
    worker_processes  1;
          
    
    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }
    
    
    http {
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;
    
    
        sendfile        on;
        #tcp_nopush     on;
    
        #keepalive_timeout  0;
        keepalive_timeout  65;
    
        #gzip  on;
    
        server {
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  localhost;
    
        location /services/processor/ {

        # below code should pass anything sent from localhost/services/processor/api/foobar
        # to the url localhost:4040/api/foobar
    
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4040$request_uri;
        
        proxy_set_header content-type "application/json";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    
        location / {
    
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080; 
    
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try: `proxy_pass http://localhost:4040/;`

Comment: @RichardSmith That works, but why does it work? How come I don't need a $request_uri variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
location /services/processor/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4040$request_uri;
    ...
}
```

with:

```
location /services/processor/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4040/;
    ...
}
```

Consider the POST to `http://localhost/services/processor/api/format`.

The stated objective is to proxy to `http://localhost:4040/api/format`.

The value of `$request_uri` is `/services/processor/api/format`.

So your original implementation will proxy to `http://localhost:4040/services/processor/api/format`.

---

The desired behaviour is to replace the string `/services/processor/` with `/` **before** sending the URL to `localhost:4040`.

[proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) has built-in functionality to achieve this.

When used within a *prefix location*, the value of the location is replaced with the value of the *optional URI*.